# why singlechildscrollviewbar is not working, I want it to scroll entire listview.builder

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, dart, singlechildscrollview

I am adding the scrollviewbar. When I click on the show more, it will expand the card in gridview.builder. As soon as it expands, it shows bottom overflow but instead of that, i want the   listview.builder to be scrolled. This masterListMobView is  being imported to other parent. Their also, I have tried using singlechildscrollviewbar

```
  Widget masterListMobView(List<dynamic> fieldList, BuildContext context){
    var myFields = List.from(widget.screenDefinition['fieldDetails']['fields']);
    myFields.removeAt(0);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: widget.screenDefinition['data'].length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          keyValuePairOfData(widget.screenDefinition['data'],
              widget.screenDefinition['fieldDetails']['fields']);
          return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 3, bottom: 3, left: 10, right: 10),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Card(
                    elevation: 0,
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  const Chip(
                                    elevation: 0,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                    backgroundColor:Color(0XFF5444AB),
                                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    ),
                                    label: SizedBox(
                                      child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Details: ',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(child:
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      if (widget
                                          .screenDefinition['fieldDetails']
                                      ['fields']
                                          .length >
                                          2) ...[
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              showField[index] = !showField[index];
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            showField[index]
                                                ? 'Show Less'
                                                : 'Show More',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                              color: Color.fromRGBO(151, 152, 163, 1),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              showField[index] = !showField[index];
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Icon(
                                            showField[index]
                                                ? Icons.arrow_drop_up
                                                : Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                            size: 28,
                                            color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                151, 152, 163, 1),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ]
                                    ],
                                  )
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              GridView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                gridDelegate:  const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                                  mainAxisExtent: 60,
                                ),
                                itemCount: showField[index]?myFields.length: 4 ,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
                                if (myFields[index1] != null &&
                                    myFields[index1]['isMainField']
                                        .toString() ==
                                        'true' &&
                                    myFields[index1]['isVisible'].toString() ==
                                        'true'
                                    && myFields[index1]['display_name']['en'].toString() !=
                                        'ID') {
                                  return Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                myFields[index1]
                                                ['display_name']['en'],
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                      151, 152, 163, 1),
                                                ),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              ),
                                              Wrap(
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    keyVal[index][myFields[index1]
                                                    ['key']] !=
                                                        null
                                                        ? keyVal[index][
                                                    myFields
                                                    [index1]['key']]!
                                                        : '',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 14,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.w400,
                                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                    overflow:
                                                    TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      if (index1 % 2 == 0 &&
                                          index1 <
                                              myFields.length -
                                                  1) // Add vertical line for even indices and not for the last column
                                        Container(
                                          width: 1.0,
                                          height: 40.0,
                                          color: Colors
                                              .grey, // Customize the line color here
                                        ),
                                      const SizedBox(width: 10.0,)
                                    ],
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return const SizedBox.shrink();
                                }
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorted this problem